# login via facebook in Xcart based ecommerce website

Tags: smarty, facebook-php-sdk, fbconnect, x-cart, fbloginview

I have to integrate facebook login in an e-commerce website made in X-cart 4.7.6. There are no add-ons available for this version and I am not able to bypass login validation, I wanted to log user in  just by using fb id. Until now , i have been successful in fetching permissions and data from Facebook when user clicks on fb-login button and check that if the particular user is an existing user or a new user. Based on this the data is entered into existing database.

Now I have been trying to set `($allow_login)` true and bypass all visible login validation from all files i guess.But yet it doesn't work. Suggest me some ideas or ways to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried **Social_Login** module ? http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Social_Login_(former_Janrain_Engage)_module#Facebook_setup

Comment: I tried using janrain social login module but login is still an issue, can anyone suggest me what is token url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that there is no ready-made module, but actually it exists: it is included in X-Cart GoldPlus by default, but if you use a "younger" package called X-Cart Gold, you may purchase  this addon separately for $99: https://market.x-cart.com/addons/social-login.html

Comment: The problem in using this addon is that it shows " powered by janrain" and our client doesnt want that. And due to unavailability of other addons for this version, custom coding is the only option i have i guess.